# Changes to Wordpress Site not showing when logged out

Tags: html, css, wordpress, divi

I've recently transferred a wordpress website from http to https. After this transition the website stopped loading properly when not logged in, but it loads fine when logged in. While investigating further I also discovered that this only occurred on certain pages of the site.

So I looked for some solutions to the problem and tried disabling a few plugins. But I discovered that when I make a change (for example disabling a plugin or changing the layout) the change only appears if I am logged in, and doesn't show at all if I am logged out and viewing the site.

I have tried clearing the cache on the website disabling and re-enabling all plugins but nothing has worked.
This is how the site looks when logged in:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB0KO.png
And you can see how the site looks while logged out here: [www.onlyphysics.org](http://www.onlyphysics.org)
The theme I am using is Divi.

I would be very grateful for any help I could get on this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that CSS files are not being loaded (404 in console). This relates to css static cache. Browser is still looking for the old css generated file.

Go to Divi Theme Options > Builder > Advanced > Static CSS File Generation
And also open your site in Incognito or private window afterwards to see. There might also be additional caching on your site, which you'll need to empty afterwards to.

More info / Source: https://divitheme.net/clear-divi-cache/

[image: 404 in console]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did this while also disabling some caching plugins and purging the cache again, and it seemed to fix the issue. There's still the issue that changes I make to the site don't show up if I'm not logged in.